# com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError error with DSE on AWS

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

Getting below error trying to install DSE via opscenter

Permission Denied

```
com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:594)
com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:475)
com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:365)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
clj_ssh.ssh$ssh_sftp_cmd$fn__18257.invoke(ssh.clj:791)
clj_ssh.ssh$ssh_sftp_cmd.invokeStatic(ssh.clj:791)
clj_ssh.ssh$ssh_sftp_cmd.invoke(ssh.clj:754)
clj_ssh.ssh$sftp.invokeStatic(ssh.clj:825)
clj_ssh.ssh$sftp.doInvoke(ssh.clj:795)
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:494)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_command$fn__18953$fn__18955$fn__18956.invoke(common.clj:983)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_command$fn__18953$fn__18955.invoke(common.clj:982)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_command$fn__18953.invoke(common.clj:973)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_command.invokeStatic(common.clj:955)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_command.invoke(common.clj:938)
lcm.jobs.multinode.install.InstallJob.run(install.clj:318)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_job.invokeStatic(common.clj:73)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_job.invoke(common.clj:68)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$process_run__18557$fn__18558.invoke(common.clj:91)
clojure.core.async$thread_call$fn__4888.invoke(async.clj:434)
clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Environment**

- Opscenter 6.1
- DSE 5.1.1
- PORT 22 is open

**Troubleshoot tried**

- Manually SSH working fine
- Same user is able to install DSE manually

Comment: Trying to run in AWS vpc do i need to setup ?? vsftpd on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpsCenter LCM dev here. When LCM begins to deploy a node, it copies a helper script to ~/meld.pyz, using the home-directory of the login-user specified in your machine credential. This error occurs when LCM encounters a write-permissions error copying that file. Investigate the homedir and permissions for your login-user and ensure that you can create that file-path.

If you have DataStax support or a sales rep, feel free to inquire about the status of OPSC-7899, which is the internal ID of the ticket we're using to track this improvement request.